# How to stop my javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know how to stop the `ns()` function.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <style>

    .buttons {
        width: 300px;
        margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
    }

    .number {
        width: 300px;
        margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
        height: 250px;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="buttons">
    <button type="button" id="start">Start</button>
    <button type="button" id="stop">Stop</button>
</div>

<div class="number"></div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

var min = 0;
var max = 21;

function wout(i) {

    setTimeout(function() {

        $('.number').append(i + '<br>');

    }, i * 500);

}

function ns() {

    for (var i = min; i < max; i++) {

        wout(i);

    }

}

$('#start').click(function() {

    ns();

});

$('#stop').click(function() {

    ns().stop();

});

});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean the timeouts? Those have nothing to do with the function `ns`.

Comment: Your `ns` function contains only a loop. It'll end when `i = 20`. If you want to stop the timeouts that are created when `ns()` calls `wout()`, use `clearTimeout()`

Comment: You can't stop ns.

Comment: `ns().stop()` does not make sense. what do you want to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can't stop the `ns()` function as it does this:

- loop 0 to 21
- *queuing* updates
- finished loop
- wait for updates
- update .number

the loop 0..21 happens effectively instantly and will not be interrupted by any UI event.  Javascript is single-threaded, so the for loop holds up that thread while it loops. Only after `ns()` has finished will the javascript processor start handling inputs such as click and the setTimeouts.  ie when you click `#stop` 0.25 seconds after `#start` (ie before first number appears) the `ns()` loop has *already* finished.

You *can* stop the effect of `wout()`, why may be what you are asking.

One option would be to keep a record of all the timeouts and use `clearTimeout` when you click stop.

```js
var min = 0;
var max = 21;
var timeouts = [];
$("#start").prop("disabled", false);
$("#stop").prop("disabled", true);

function wout(i) {
  var t = setTimeout(function() {
    $('.number').append(i + '<br>');
  }, i * 500);
  timeouts.push(t);
}

function ns() {
  for (var i = min; i < max; i++) {
    wout(i);
  }
}

$('#start').click(function() {
  $("#start").prop("disabled", true);
  $("#stop").prop("disabled", false);
  $(".number").text("");
  ns();
});

$('#stop').click(function() {
  $("#start").prop("disabled", false);
  $("#stop").prop("disabled", true);
  $.each(timeouts, function() {
    clearTimeout(this);
  });
});
```

```css
.buttons {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
}

.number {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <button type="button" id="start">Start</button>
  <button type="button" id="stop">Stop</button>
</div>

<div class="number"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

setTimeout does mean that you function is going to run for  i * 500, it delays excecution of your function for specified time.

Comment: This didn’t really clarify or answer the question…